# timeout stringwithcontentsofurl

Tags: nsstring

I have this call to stringwithcontentsofurl:

```
[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:nil  error:nil];
```

How can I give that a simple timeout?
I don't want to use threads or operation queues (the content of the url is about 100 characters), I just don't want to wait too long when the connection is slow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, you might be best off using the `NSURLConnection` class method `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`; it'll return a data object you can initialize your string with (using `-initWithData:encoding:`). You can specify a timeout by creating an `NSURLRequest` using its `-initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` method, then pass that request as the first parameter of `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

Comment: The only problem with this is that you don't get the built-in guessing of encoding that you do with `+stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`, so you'd have to roll your own.

Answer (score 17):

Here's my take on it:

```
NSString* link = @"http://example.com";
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link] cachePolicy:0 timeoutInterval:5];
NSURLResponse* response=nil;
NSError* error=nil;
NSData* data=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString* stringFromServer = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```