# How can I set the 30 sec timeout? NSURL

Tags: iphone, timeout

How can I set the 30 sec timeout? NSURL

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError* error;
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this previous SO question [timeout stringwithcontentsofurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027056/timeout-stringwithcontentsofurl)

In this case, you might be best off using the `NSURLConnection` class method `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:;` it'll return a data object you can initialize your string with (using `-initWithData:encoding:`). You can specify a timeout by creating an `NSURLRequest` using its `-initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` method, then pass that request as the first parameter of `+sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`.

Comment: The only problem with this is that you don't get the built-in guessing of encoding that you do with `+stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:`, so you'd have to roll your own.

Answer (score 3):

When you create an `NSURLRequest` from your `NSURL`, use `requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:` to specify a timeout interval in seconds.  For instance:

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: myUrl 
    cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
    timeoutInterval:30.0];
```